# i can't use base64encoder in Amazon ec2 load balancing

Tags: amazon-ec2, base64, load-balancing

---

Hi, i'm running 2 server in amazon ec2 under load balancing apps, both of them using the same script. If i send curl data with base64 encryption on it, the load balancing won't proceed the base64 encryption. But if send the curl data directly to server, the base64 can be proceed.

everytime i send curl data with base64 on it via load balancing, i always receive this error:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my.host.server; nodename nor servname provided, or not known

can anyone help me with this?